# Exporting a piped command without evaluating output?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, kill

I'm trying to set an `export` that would effectively `kill` a process based on the PID that `pgrep` feeds it. Running the command `kill $(pgrep myAppName)` appears to work (if *'myAppName'* were the name of an actual running process)... But how would you save this command as an exported environment variable? Every variation of the command that I could think of seems to try and evaluate `pgrep myAppName` into something like `20137` (or a similar PID value), and running the exported variable works the first time, but obviously won't work after that since the exported command is actually `kill 20137`, where that process has already been terminated.

How can I get this to be properly saved in a variable, so I can just type something like `$KILL_APPNAME` to kill that process, every single time the command is run?

Comment: Use `pkill myAppName`...

Comment: Storing a command in a shell variable (whether `export`ed or not — it wouldn't really need to be exported) sounds like [the wrong solution to problem you're not mentioning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You could use seom trickery with `eval` but a shell function or even an `alias` sounds like a better way to do this.

Comment: Or `killall`. I think the direct answer to your question is "use a function", though.

Comment: @Celada True, I'm asking this question to solve 2 problems... But I'm not [shaving a yak](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving), if that's what you're trying to say. I'm simply trying to learn how to solve one problem on a broader scale, while using another issue as a use case. Two birds, one stone.

Comment: @jasonwryan Well that solves the smaller issue, but I'd still like an answer to the actual question... And no, I don't wish to write a shell script in order to execute 1 line of code. Haven't looked into `alias` yet, but i'll check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I *think* you're trying to do needs `eval` in order to work:

```
THING="eval kill \$(pgrep myAppName)"
$THING
```

but it's awkward and doesn't work by default in all shells (for example it doesn't work by default in `zsh` although an option can be set to make it work). Whatever you are trying to do is most likely better solved with something cleaner and easier like a function:

```
kill_my_app() {
    kill $(pgrep myAppName)
}
kill_my_app
```

Or, as others have pointed out in comments, just use `pkill` or `killall` which does exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I've learned a lot here! But what's the escape sequence for (the `\` before the `$`)? What does it do in this scenario?

Comment: To be clear it's not a `\`` (backtick), it's a `\​` (backslash). I think you had the same trouble I had getting it to show up correctly in the markup syntax before I edited this comment to fix it. It prevents the `$` from being interpreted while you are setting the `THING` variable. The `$` only gets interpreted later, when `eval` is executed. Try `set -x` to enable debugging in your shell to see what it's doing. Turn debugging off again with `set +x`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Seems to have something to do with stack exchange's metadata printing it out as a backtick (as you can see, you've also done here)... Might need to double-escape it to print out correctly in a code wrapper. But once again, thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: Yeah, geez, the markup syntax really gave us trouble here. I had to edit my comment, like, 5 times to get it to look right and even then I used a really dirty trick to force the backslash to display! :-) Anyway, you're welcome.